# Find the minimum positive integer divisible by both 2 and N

Tags: c++

I am still learning C++ and having an ECPC Competition tomorrow.
You are given a positive integer N. Find the minimum positive integer divisible by both 2 and N.
What should I do in the for loop? (still not completed)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>> n;
    for(int i; ???;i++)
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: isnt `2*N` divisible by `2` and `N` ? Only if `N` is divisible by `2` there might be a smaller number that fits. Do the maths first.

Comment: [`std::lcm(n, 2)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lcm) ?

Comment: It's ether N if it is divisible by 2, or N*2

Comment: [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/430766)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any loop.

There are two cases. Either `N` is not divisible by `2`, then all integers divisible by `N` and `2` are of the form

```
x = N * 2 * y
```

The smallest of those `x` has `y==1`.

The second case is when `N` is divisible by `2`, then all integers divisible by `N` and `2` are of the form

```
x = N * y
```

The smallest of those `x` has `y==1`.

TL;DR: Do the maths first!

Answer (score 1):

The result is N if N is divisible by 2, otherwise it's N*2.

```
int result = (N%2 == 0) ? N : N*2;
```

Comment: Oh, I see someone already answered the question... I'll keep this answer to illustrate the use of ternary operators in this case. But are you sure this is problem's statement? It seems too easy for a CS competition

Comment: "too ease for a CS competition" its a trap. As with most of such competiion tasks you can either first solve the problem then write the code or first write complicated code and then wonder why it hits the time limit ;)

Comment: Are we sure that this is the optimal solution? I've encountered this on codegoda 2022 trial question, but it failed on test case number 5. This is exactly my answer and now wondering what's wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int i,N;
scanf("%d",&N);
for(i=1;i<100;i++)
  {
    if(i%2==0&&i%N==0)
      {
         if(i<12)
           {
             printf("%d",i);
           }
      }
  }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should try using

```
int i=0;
while(true)
{
    i++;
    if((i%2==0) && (i%n==0))
    {
        cout<<i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: (I didn't downvote this answer) It's an O(N), Where N is n*2. It's a very simple problem, don't brute force. You can solve it in O(1) just with a very little analysis :)